# sjPlot is loaded but R complains that it could not find sjt.corr function

Tags: correlation, sjplot

Does anyone have a clue for why stj.corr fails here?

```
library(sjPlot)
view_df(cars) # works fine
sjt.corr(cars)# produces error Error in sjt.corr(cars) : could not find function "sjt.corr"
```

Answer (score 1):

tab_corr(cars) would do the job! I guess the other function is deprecated